# PayPal REST Api Brazilian BRL Currency

Tags: paypal

I'm developing a project to integrate PayPal. The project needs *paypal* method and *credit card* method. *Paypal* payment is working perfectly but, the *credit card* payment isn't.

When I try to create a *credit card* payment the remote server returns an error:

```
{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"transactions[0].amount.currency","issue":"Value is not supported at this time"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"2c57c4279a510"}
```

If I change the currency to *EUR* or *USD* it works.

```
Amount amount = new Amount();
amount.total = "15.23";
//amount.currency = "EUR";
//amount.currency = "USD";
amount.currency = "BRL";
//amount.currency = PayPalManager.Currency;
amount.details = amountDetails;
```

After some research I found at [PayPal Currencies Code](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/) that

> (Brazilian Real) This currency is supported as a payment currency and a currency balance for in-country PayPal accounts only.

**Question:**

1. The classic API support *credit card* payment for *BRL Currency* ?
2. Is there any workaroud using the REST Api ?
3. If paypal definitely don't support it. Then why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes "BRL" is not supported yet for Credit card payments . You can check the credit card currency support for REST API at below link and it supports only USD/GBP/JPY/EUR/CAD at the moment

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/

For Classic API too , BRL is not supported as a credit card currency, check the below link :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Eshan but, before I accept your answer, do you have any clue about why it's not supported ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the answer for that as this is something related to PayPal business Strategy. Might be in future you will see the expansion for credit card currencies too .